# mysql, utf-8 column: how to select only case-sensitive?

Tags: mysql, select, utf-8, case-sensitive

I work with utf-8 strings. They should be stored in a MySQL database table. That's why I decided to choose some of utf-8 collations for several columns. Now I see the choice in not as clear as I guessed. The problem is the SELECT statement should be case sensitive. But it is not.

The first option is to choose another utf-8 collation (the only non-ci collation is utf8_bin as far as I see). Is it a solution? The second one is to use BINARY in the SELECT statement:

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where BINARY col3='CasE_sENsiTive';
```

That's quite simple, but it reduces the performance at least for x10 times and even more. 
My table has 1 index, and it works fine without BINARY (no index = slow).

What's a solution in my situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some sample data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve the performance for case-sensitive search in the following way:

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col3='Case_sEnsiTive' AND BINARY col3="CasE_sENsiTive";
```

However, if there is no good reason for having a case-insensitive collation, I strongly advise to use `utf8_bin` as collation.

Answer (score 2):

Either use your provided example, or, if you will *always* treat the column as case-sensitive, assign a case-sensitive collation to it (i.e. a collation that ends in `_cs` [case-sensitive] or `_bin` [binary]). See [Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) in the MySQL reference.