# MySQL binary in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can you assign a binary parameter in code igniter, so that it will return a case sensitive query?

I am trying to do this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `column` = 'value'
```

but I don't know how to. Where do I place the BINARY in my CI query.

This is my query

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('admin')->where(array('user'=>$username, 'pass'=>$password))->get();
        $temp = $this->db->last_query();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                if($row->type == "1"){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('admin', $temp);
                    return "admin";
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_userdata('manager', $temp);
                    return "manager";
                }           
            }
        }else{
            $query = $this->db->select('id')->from('user')->where(array('user'=>$username, 'pass'=>$password))->get();
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach ($query->result() as $row){

                    if($this->session->userdata('sessionid') == ""){
                        session_regenerate_id();
                        $this->session->set_userdata('sessionid', session_id());

                    }else{
                        $this->session->set_userdata('sessionid', session_id());
                    }
                    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('sessionid');
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user', $username);

                    return "user";      
                }
            }else{
                return "none";
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want a string comparison to be case sensitive, you should use a case sensitive *collation* rather than a binary comparison.  Moreover, if you have a column whose values are case sensitive, you can (and should) *define the column* to use a case sensitive collation by default—then you won't need to specify anything more in your queries themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql, utf-8 column: how to select only case-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237129/mysql-utf-8-column-how-to-select-only-case-sensitive)

Comment: @NathanTuggy im looking for a way to set it in codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('admin')->where('BINARY user = '.$username.' and pass = '.$password.'')->get();
```

Or make it simple like this

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY column = "value"');
$query->result();
```